Develop credit rating based on binary variable (in R preferably)
I work with credit data in R. I have a loan dataset where I have borrower and credit specific variables and a binary indicator default/notdefault. At first step I do logit and get probability of default (PD). What i want to do after:
Have something like credit rating model based on these PDs. For example, class 1: PD<0.2, class 2: 0.2<PD<0.4 etc.
This number of classes should be econometrically/statistically optimal.
Find these thresholds between classes.
How can i achieve this?
I thought that based on PD and some other characteristics I can do cluster analysis and then use these clusters as the dependent variable in ordered logit or something like that. But I am afraid of correlation and other stuff. I am also puzzled about proving what is the optimal number of clusters. How can I choose? It would be good if you can provide R code ideas but not neccessarily

"This number of classes should be econometrically/statistically optimal. " How is this 'optimal' defined? What are the considerations in creating these classes, what is it supposed to achieve?

To add to @SextusEmpiricus's comment:  creating such classes seems to be an arbitrary exercise with no clear value at present.

These should be credit risk classes. And based on class bank should do provisioning.
The analogue of what I want to do is Vintage Score classification of 4 categories and thresholds between them. Is there any logic why there are 4 of them? Why not make 5, or 3.

@DanyloKrasovytskyi what are the considerations surrounding that provisioning? And which potential actions/decisions are available? You have to describe and quantify the problem. Three, four or five, there is certainly no logic if there is no background onto which such logic can be applied.

@SextusEmpiricus I have "credit risk indicator" which is what banks have to provision currently. I can reverse engineer LGD, I know the sum of loan (approx EAD). If I have new classes I can take their medians as PD. EADLGDPD I will have new value of credit risk, which I can compare with the old one. If the new classification is better banks will make lower provisions.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

„ I have "credit risk indicator" which is what banks have to provision currently.” @DanyloKrasovytskyi this doesn't explain why you need categories. why do banks use categories. What do they do with them? How are they used? Why would you care about the categories?

If there is no problem with too many or too few categories, then why should you be bothered with it? On the other hand, if there can be problems then explain/inform what those problems are. Such explanation/information has little to do with statistics. You need to provide it before you can start thinking about applying statistics.
